# What to do to fetch data quickly from multiple joins?

Tags: sql

Interviewer asked me :

> To normalize the database you brake tables into multiple tables. And to fetch data you will use joins that would slow down your database performance. What would you do next to fetch data quickly?

I didn't find any answer?

Can somebody suggest anything??

Comment: Joins don't necessarily slow down performance.  The interviewer is asking for the answer "create indexes".  However, you should have already done so when you declared the primary (and perhaps the foreign key) relationships for the data model.  That fact that the interviewer would suggest creating  tables with no primary keys indicates a major flaw in the question.

Comment: Indexes, optimizer hints, analyze explain plans to see where costly operations are being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can elaborate your answer to any extent. But Indexing your joining fields properly should suffice and reindex when necessary. you can use hints to push performance its not usually required.